# Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource @id/search_edit_frame

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rendering, searchview

> Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource @id/search_edit_frame

This is the rendering error I'm getting in my xml file. I think it has something to do with my `support.v7.SearchView` below is my xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_ricerca"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_border_backgroud"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/testo_ricerca"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tasto_ricerca"
        android:background="@color/trans"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tasto_ricerca"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I change the `<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` to `<SearchView` the error disappears, but that's not a good solution for me because I would have to change all my java code to work with the `SearchView` instead of the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ? why does it happen? I don't think there is anything wrong with my xml.

**Edit:**

Added screenshot of the error

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Related [Couldn't resolve resource @id/visible when using TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42079386/7034327)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have lot of cache memory data are store in `Android Studio` that time this type of error is coming..

There are many way to solve it.

1. Quickest way to do that is `File` → `Invalidate caches / Restart...`
   → `Just Restart`.
2. Right click on `project` and `Synchronize ...Project`
3. click on `Build menu` --> select `Clean Project` and then `Rebuild
   it`.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! but the error is still there

Comment: @Daniele post the screenShot of the screen.

Comment: Please, have a look at my question, I've added the screenshot

Comment: @Daniele rendering problem only display in `API 23` all other work fine.

Comment: Yes in fact I'm always using API 23... Could this be a bug? Even because the app works fine when run on the simulator

Comment: @Daniele Check You have latest Version is `Update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116467/discussion-between-daniele-and-ironman).

Comment: the same error happened to me, and I found that I forgot to specify custom 'id'. after i did, i needed to apply @Ironman answer and the problem was gone

Answer (score 16):

To resolve this issue, provide an

```
android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
```

attribute to a parent view such as

```
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

or any ViewGroup that is parent to your SearchView.

For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/my_app_bar_height">

  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout />
```

Comment: This is the bomb, works great for me ! Only missing "@" in the android id resource. :)

Comment: @Red M  Is it suppose to be `android:id="+id/search_edit_frame"` or `android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"` ??

Comment: it works for me using android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<SearchView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/searchView"
android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
android:queryHint="Search"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
```

> add above line to parent layout that did the trick for me

Answer (score -1):

**Here is an easy one solution.**

There is no need of invalidating cache Or restarting.
Just add below line into your strings.xml file and problem will get solved.

```
 <item name="search_edit_frame" type="id"/>
```

Bingo!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but in eclipse IDE and I solved it by 
1- click on project --> clean and it solved the problem with me