# Couldn't resolve resource @id/visible when using TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

Couldn't resolve resource `@id/visible` when using `TextInputLayout` on `appcompat-v7:25.x.x`

Tried these steps below, but the problem is still persist:

1. Rebuild Project
2. Clean and Rebuild Project
3. Clear Cache and
   Restart Android Studio

Below is the code in the layout file.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Below is the message displayed in Android Studio

> Rendering Problems.
>
> Couldn't resolve resource `@id/visible`
>
> Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

NOTE: `@id/visible` is not present in the code.

Comment: Where is your `android:id="@id/visible"` View?

Comment: i don`t know, i didn`t use it id in code

Comment: Whose code is that? Isn't it yours?

Comment: my code, but i not use view with @id/visible in this layout

Comment: Maybe it's referenced in some styles or themes?

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems a bug... even when the layout is just composed of one TextInputLayout in a FrameLayout....

Answer (score 225, accepted):

This nags one with the Rendering Problems window

How to fix: add these values to any values file (the filename doesn't appear to matter, I use `ids.xml`, you can use an existing one as well, such as `colors.xml` or `strings.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="visible" type="id"/>
    <item name="masked" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Perfect! Created `ids.xml` file under `res.values` package with the content above

Comment: Yes, this works. I think this will cause problems later when the original bug is resolved, so I would recommend to stay alert.

Comment: instead of creating any other xml file, I've added these lines to `strings.xml`.

Comment: @Prabs, yes, the name of the resource file doesn't matter, wherever it is, it can be added to `colors.xml` also

Comment: @Shujito Yes, it works. Please answer why it worked and what was the issue which caused this error.

Answer (score 42):

It most likely is a bug, and it has been [filed in the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130611).

Meanwhile, you may try to switch the API version in the editor to 19 or below, though [you may see some minor differences in the design output](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230766#c5).

Answer (score 13):

No Need To Change API

Couldn't resolve resource `@string/faq_customer_service`

or

Couldn't resolve resource `@id/visible`

or

Couldn't resolve resource `@id/masked`

The solution is if you implement `TextInputLayout` the above problems may arise ... so Simply add those id or strings to xml files as their property.

Comment: I didn't understand

Answer (score 5):

Add the value below tag in strings.xml file:

```
 <item name="visible" type="id"/>
 <item name="masked" type="id"/>
```